# async/await bad practice under Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin, async-await

Currently I am porting an existing C# Windows 8 / iOS app to Android (with Xamarin).

I used a lot of async/await for file IO, dialogs, network, etc…

What happens when the app is paused/suspended during an await call?
Under Windows and iOS there are two possibilities:

- the app is resumed later, as if nothing had happened
- the app is terminated if memory is low.

In both cases, there is no memoy leak, there are no changes in control flow.

However, under Android, an Activity can be destroyed and recreated while the process stays alive. In my understanding of async/await this means:

- an unclosed dialog will wait forever, meaning that objects which were accessible from the caller ("this", local variables etc.) will stay in memory forever (memory leak)
- when an awaited network request finishes while the former activity has already been destroyed by Android, the code after "await" (e.g. file write) could collide because two running instances of the Activity exist.

Are my assumtions true? If yes, what can be done? (without making the program as complicated as before of the invention of async/await)

Comment: tasks that don't deal with networking and are about 20ms are OK to just run synchronously

Comment: @Sarge Borsch: I am porting an existing Windows 8 app to Android. Windows 8 requires async for file read/write and for dialogs. I want to reuse as much code as possible. So I don't want to remove 100 awaits and change all helper methods. (I am using Xamarin, so I could theoretically reuse almost everything.)

Comment: this is only in theory... chances are you will have to change not only entire UI code/markup, but also some real logic

Answer (score 1):

An Android Activity is guaranteed to call OnPause before the activity is deactivated/destroyed and OnResume when it starts up (see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

How about if you had a CancellationTokenSource available from your Activity.  Then in OnPause you can call Cancel and then use:

```
try
{
    // Your async code
    ...
}
catch (OperationCancelledException e)
{
}
```

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155759.aspx for cancelling async tasks.

More a suggestion than a definitive answer, but I hope it helps.

Edit:

When I started introducing async/await into my code I found it to be like a zombie virus.  Once you start asyncing you find it spreads throughout the rest of your code.  It may be that you've got lots of async calls for the same reason.  There are generally two rules to follow:

1. Declare methods as `public async Task Foo()` instead of `public async void Foo()`
2. [Don't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

In my own practice, I've discovered 2 places where you can break these general rules.

1. If you're at the 'top' (i.e. the UI) of your code, there may be places where you have to declare code as async void because the delegate you're overriding takes void as a return type.  A typical example of this is with a button.Click method.
2. I had a database call which looked up a single value in a database.  If I converted that to async, *lots* of my code elsewhere would have to change.  I discovered that if you're guaranteed, and I mean **guaranteed**, to be at the 'bottom' of your code, specifically that none of the methods below the one you're calling use async, then you can safely call .Result on a Task.  This saved me from asyncing half my code unnecessarily.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems to be a reasonable solution. But that would mean a lot of work. I have 140 times "await" and about 40 async methods where I would have to include the try-catch block. I would have to do that with every async method, even if the average running time is only 20 ms or so. Ok, I will wait for other suggestions. And if there are no ones, I will mark your suggestion as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service to perform these long running tasks.  Another option would be to use a headless fragment (one without a view and that it's `.RetainInstance` property set to `true`).

Comment: Use a service: I have 140 times "await" in my app. Most of them are not long running tasks but only take 20 ms or so. Services would make everything complicated. Fragment with RetainInstance: Could you elaborate on that?