# Can async/await be made aware of the Android activity lifecycle?

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin

I've been wondering about the usage of async/await to produce responsive UIs on Android. I have been using a simple pub/sub wrapper service around the async functions (Which is quite a lot of boilerplate but works) but i've had this itch on my side that tells me there should be a better way.

The need for the wrapper service stems from the fact that activities on android get "recycled" (destroyed and recreated) on configuration changes (device rotation, language change...) so if i fire an async function the await callback might be produced on a destroyed activity and all kinds of bad could originate from that.

Could the async backend somehow be made aware that the code should fire off in a different object (The newly-created activity) without compiler dark magics?

**Rationale**: Sharing code between iOS and Android is all sweet and easy using Xamarin until you crash into this problem. Should this be somehow solved/implemented, i see the potential for common controllers between both platforms.

Edit:
I've decided to work around this with an Event bus (TinyMessenger) while i understand the `SynchronizationContext` solution proposed by @Servy

Comment: Interesting question, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's specifically designed to do exactly that.  Whenever you hit an `await` it will inspect the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current`, and it will post the continuation to that context.  If you want a particular callback to to to a particular context, you just need to set the current context to a `SynchronizationContext` object that appropriate marshals your callbacks...however you need them marshaled.

Comment: Interesting... This question originated exactly from me glancing into the MSDN page for that class. I will look deeper into the matter